# What is the best way to find the digit at n position in a decimal number?

Tags: c#, algorithm, rounding

#### Background

I'm working on a symmetric rounding class and I find that I'm stuck with regards to how to best find the number at position x that I will be rounding. I'm sure there is an efficient mathematical way to find the single digit and return it without having to resort to string parsing.

#### Problem

Suppose, I have the following (C#) psuedo-code:

```
var position = 3;
var value = 102.43587m;
// I want this no ↑ (that is 5)

protected static int FindNDigit(decimal value, int position)
{
    // This snippet is what I am searching for
}
```

Also, it is worth noting that if my value is a whole number, I will need to return a zero for the result of FindNDigit.

Does anyone have any hints on how I should approach this problem? Is this something that is blaringly obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: You shouldn't be using "var"'s like that. If you know that it is a decimal you should specify it right when you are declaring.

Comment: @VoodooChild I think thats subjective, i mean they are int and decimals in the final code.. I take it more as style.. and style-wise, well everybody has its own preference.

by the way, awesome use of the ↑ up arrow!

Comment: I don't use vars for primitive types because it is a subjective choice, I use vars for all other types though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
using System;

public static class DecimalExtensions
{
    public static int DigitAtPosition(this decimal number, int position)
    {
        if (position <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Position must be positive.");
        }

        if (number < 0)
        {
            number = Math.Abs(number);
        }

        number -= Math.Floor(number);

        if (number == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        if (position == 1)
        {
            return (int)(number * 10);
        }

        return (number * 10).DigitAtPosition(position - 1);
    }
}
```

**Edit**:
If you wish, you may separate the recursive call from the initial call, to remove the initial conditional checks during recursion:

```
using System;

public static class DecimalExtensions
{
    public static int DigitAtPosition(this decimal number, int position)
    {
        if (position <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Position must be positive.");
        }

        if (number < 0)
        {
            number = Math.Abs(number);
        }

        return number.digitAtPosition(position);
    }

    static int digitAtPosition(this decimal sanitizedNumber, int validPosition)
    {
        sanitizedNumber -= Math.Floor(sanitizedNumber);

        if (sanitizedNumber == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        if (validPosition == 1)
        {
            return (int)(sanitizedNumber * 10);
        }

        return (sanitizedNumber * 10).digitAtPosition(validPosition - 1);
    }
```

---

Here's a few tests:

```
using System;
using Xunit;

public class DecimalExtensionsTests
{
                         // digit positions
                         // 1234567890123456789012345678
    const decimal number = .3216879846541681986310378765m;

    [Fact]
    public void Throws_ArgumentException_if_position_is_zero()
    {
        Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => number.DigitAtPosition(0));
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Throws_ArgumentException_if_position_is_negative()
    {
        Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => number.DigitAtPosition(-5));
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Works_for_1st_digit()
    {
        Assert.Equal(3, number.DigitAtPosition(1));
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Works_for_28th_digit()
    {
        Assert.Equal(5, number.DigitAtPosition(28));
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Works_for_negative_decimals()
    {
        const decimal negativeNumber = -number;
        Assert.Equal(5, negativeNumber.DigitAtPosition(28));
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Returns_zero_for_whole_numbers()
    {
        const decimal wholeNumber = decimal.MaxValue;
        Assert.Equal(0, wholeNumber.DigitAtPosition(1));
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Returns_zero_if_position_is_greater_than_the_number_of_decimal_digits()
    {
        Assert.Equal(0, number.DigitAtPosition(29));
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Does_not_throw_if_number_is_max_decimal_value()
    {
        Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => decimal.MaxValue.DigitAtPosition(1));
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Does_not_throw_if_number_is_min_decimal_value()
    {
        Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => decimal.MinValue.DigitAtPosition(1));
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Does_not_throw_if_position_is_max_integer_value()
    {
        Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => number.DigitAtPosition(int.MaxValue));
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this solution cover that the others do not? Does it deal with edge cases?

Comment: Yes, it should deal with all edge cases.  The most upvoted answer deals with too few values before overflowing, IMO.

Comment: (not to mention it doesn't compile)

Comment: Accepted because this solution deals with real-world edge cases.

Answer (score 29):

```
(int)(value * Math.Pow(10, position)) % 10
```

Comment: You should strip off the digits to the left of "position" first to avoid unnecessary overflows.

Comment: @mbeckish it is enough for simple cases. for complex you have to do it in loop, multiply and strip

Comment: Math.Pow() returns the type double and that upsets the compiler a bit. Besides, casting decimal to an int is really bad idea. Aren't You missing a pair of parenthesis?

Comment: @mbeckish, Andrey: Would it not also be possible to just ignore overflow in this case? As long as you aren't modifying `value` itself, there's no reason you'd need to worry about the lost data there. @Maciej Hehl: How does this look? `decimal.Floor(value * Math.Pow(10, position)) % 10`

Comment: @Maciej - the cast to int gets rid of any extra numbers to the right of the decimal point after shifting; they're not needed.

Comment: @SethO Well, it does if an overflow doesn't happen and if You take the range of values, the decimal type can store and assume a uniform distribution of values (I know, usually it's not uniform, but we know nothing about it) the probability of the overflow not happening is very very low.

Comment: With value = 10 and position = 1, this returns 0 :(

Comment: To get the last digit: `value % 10`

Answer (score 25):

How about:

```
(int)(double(value) * Math.Pow(10, position)) % 10
```

Basically you multiply by `10 ^ pos` in order to move that digit to the one's place, and then you use the modulus operator `%` to divide out the rest of the number.

Comment: +1 for including an explanation :).  I'm sure the code would include this as a comment.

Comment: I like how both simple answers are EXACTLY the same. Creepy.

Comment: With value = 10 and position = 1, this returns 0 :(

Comment: To get the last digit: `value % 10`

Answer (score 2):

Edited:  Totally had the wrong and opposite answer here.  I was calculating the position to the left of the decimal instead of the right.  See the upvoted answers for the correct code.

Comment: yeah, did you try to run it? remainder (%) doesn't work with double.

Comment: My mistake.  I quickly ran it in VS2010 interactive and used integer instead of decimal.  I'll see if Math.DivRem() will work.

Answer (score 2):

I found this one [here](http://bateru.com/news/2011/04/code-of-the-day-c-get-the-digits-from-a-number/) working:

```
public int ValueAtPosition(int value, int position)
{
    var result = value / (int)Math.Pow(10, position);
    result = result % 10;
    return result;
}
```

And also this one to know the full value (i.e.: 111, position 3 = 100 , sorry I don't know the proper name):

```
public int FullValueAtPosition(int value, int position)
{
    return this.ValueAtPosition(value, position) * (int)Math.Pow(10, position);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
protected static int FindNDigit(decimal value, int position)
{
    var index = value.ToString().IndexOf(".");
    position = position + index;
    return (int)Char.GetNumericValue(value.ToString(), position);
}
```

Comment: Yep. Missed that constraint. :(

Answer (score 0):

None of the previous solutions worked for me, so here is a working one :

`var result = value / Math.Pow(10, Math.Truncate((Math.Log10(value) + 1) - position));
return (int)(result % 10);`